# How to delete certain rows in pandas which satisfies some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas and I have dataset which are looking like this:

```
ID-cell    TOWNS      NumberOfCrimes
 1          Paris       444
 1          Berlin      333
 1          London      111        
 2          Paris       222
 2          London      555
 2          Berlin      3
 3          Paris       999
 4          Berlin      777
 4          Paris       5
 5          Paris       123
 5          Berlin      8
 6          Paris       1000
 9          Berlin      321
 12         Berlin      1
 12         Berlin      2
 12         Paris       1

        . . .
```

And its a really big dataset. I need to keep for each city just 5 rows with the highest number of crimes and rest of them to delete.

So my output should look like this:

```
ID-cell    TOWNS      NumberOfCrimes
 6          Paris       1000
 3          Paris       999     
 1          Paris       444
 2          Paris       222
 5          Paris       123

 4          Berlin      777
 1          Berlin      333
 9          Berlin      321
 5          Berlin      8

 1          London      555        
 2          London      111
```

I really appreciate the help. I am new in this. And I am working some project for Faculty and my deadline is so close.  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### sort + groupby.head

You can sort by `NumberOfCrimes` descending, then use `groupby` + `head`. Here's an example with your data extracting the single highest NumberOfCrimes by Town.

```
res = df.sort_values('NumberOfCrimes', ascending=False)\
        .groupby('TOWNS').head(1)

print(res)

   ID-cell   TOWNS  NumberOfCrimes
5        3   Paris             999
4        2  London             555
1        1  Berlin             333
```

So, for the top 2 or 3 for each town, you can use `head(2)`, `head(3)`, etc.

Comment: @Neven, Sure, no problem. Note Wen's solution is better if you only need the top one. This one is more extendable.

Comment: Your solution is better for what I need, but his solution is the good one also. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
df.sort_values('NumberOfCrimes').drop_duplicates('ID-cell',keep='last')
Out[404]: 
   ID-cell   TOWNS  NumberOfCrimes
0        1   Paris             444
4        2  London             555
5        3   Paris             999
```

Comment: I like this solution is better for just keeping the top one.

Comment: Thank you 2 very much. :) 
Can I accept two answers as correct?